# is Qt a conforming C++ implementation?

Tags: c++, qt, language-lawyer

Does the C++ standard implicitly or explicitly allow such language extensions (or use whatever other term you like) as MOC is?

That is, can we ***technically*** call Qt (including MOC) a conforming C++ implementation?

Comment: I don't see why this question deserves a downvote. Because you don't like this kind of questions?

Comment: The downvotes (not mine) are probably there because your question doesn't make sense. Qt isn't a C++ implementation at all, conforming or otherwise.

Comment: @meagar and all others: I know that Qt is a library, but along with MOC it can be considered an implementation, can't it?

Comment: @Armen No, it can't be. An "implementation" of a language generally refers to a specific compiler's interpretation of that language. Code generation != compilation. Qt and MOC are implemented *in* C++; they are not an implementation *of* C++.

Comment: An implementation of what? A preprocessor? Then you'd have to ask if MOC is a conforming implementation of (Put preprocessior standard here). Qt uses C++, it does not implement it as there is no compiler.

Comment: @meagar: In any case I believe it would be better to explain that to me in an answer or comment. My question, although terminologically incorrect, still is **somewhat** valid

Comment: @Armen No, it really isn't somewhat valid - it's completely invalid. The fundamental premise of your question is wrong. Every answer so far has basically called your question out as not making sense. Down votes are for questions which are "unclear or **not useful**".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MOC is a code generator, not a language extension. All code moc generates you could also write by hand (it would be time-consuming, mind-numbing and error-prone though). Qt uses a few macros such as Q_OBJECT, Q_SIGNALS, Q_SLOTS etc. for the declarations and to give hints to moc. This is perfectly "legal" usage of the preprocessor. The only thing you might consider non-standard is the extra step running the moc to generate the extra code when building the project. That's a matter of the build system though (and code generation is not that unusual, see parsers, IPC interfaces etc.) and outside the scope of C++ as such.

Answer (score 14):

The standard doesn't tell you that you shouldn't preprocess your files before compiling them, and that is what `moc` does, so that is perfectly legal. And Qt is a library for C++, not an implementation of the language.

Answer (score 3):

MOC is technically a preprocessor, and therefore irrelevant to the question of C++ compliance.

Comment: I believe the preprocessor is a part of implementation

Comment: The C preprocessor is; external preprocessors are outside of the standard.

Comment: @Armen believing stuff does not make it real. See geekosaur's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The *input* to MOC is not conforming C++ - MOC accepts keywords such as `slots` and `signals`. But the *output* from MOC is conforming C++.

**Edited** to reply to Frank Osterfeld's coment (I couldn't reply in a comment, I need the formatting):

`slots` and `signals` are keywords to the MOC preprocessor. If Q_MOC_RUN is defined (which it is when MOC runs), then qobjectdefs.h has:

```
#define slots slots
#define signals signals
```

which leaves them unsubstituted.

Comment: slot and signals are not keywords, they are valid preprocessor macros. The code is still valid C++, the source files compile perfectly fine without moc. moc just generates _additional_ code, it doesn't modify the existing .h or .cpp files.

Comment: It leaves them unsubstituted only for the moc run, i.e. the code generator. It does nothing to the code when gcc is run.